# How to scroll the content of an iframe using the browser's scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I had created a web page which consist of iframe. I want to scroll the iframe content using browser scrollbar. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = "jquery-2.1.4.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src = "iframe.js">
        </script>
        <style>
            button{
                position : relative;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "frame">
            <iframe src = 'demo.html' id = "sd" frameBorder='0' scrolling = "no" height = "100%" width = '100%'>
            </iframe>
        </div>
            <button id ="zoomIn">
                zoom in
            </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

On clicking the `zoomIn` button, I want the content inside the iframe to increase its size. There should not be any scrollbar in the iframe, but the scrolling should be done by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src = 'demo.html' id ='sd' frameBorder='0' scrolling = 'no' height = '100%' width = '100%'>
```

**in your css**

```
iframe { overflow:hidden; }
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the way to scroll the iframe content using browser scrollbar on zooming is by getting the height and width of the iframe content and changing the height of iframe and parent body accordingly. Following is the code

```
$("document").ready(function(){
$("#zoomIn").click(function(){
    var zoomValue = 5;
    css = 'transform: scale(' + zoomValue+ ');';
    css += '-webkit-transform: scale(' + zoomValue + ');';
    css += '-moz-transform: scale(' + zoomValue + '); ';
    css += '-o-transform: scale(' + zoomValue  + ');';
    css += 'transform-origin: left top;';
    css += '-webkit-transform-origin: left top;';
    css += '-moz-transform-origin: left top; ';
    css += '-ms-transform-origin: left top;';
    var innerBody = $("iframe").contents().find("body");
    innerBody.attr({style:css});
    $("body").css({
        'height': innerBody[0].getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px',
        'width': innerBody[0].getBoundingClientRect().width + 'px'
    });
    $("iframe").css({
        'height': innerBody[0].getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px',
        'width': innerBody[0].getBoundingClientRect().width + 'px'
    });
});
```

});